# ¿ Apache Tomcat 10 es compatible con Eclipse 2022-03?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, tomcat

sigo iniciándome en curso Java tanto asistido en clases como Online con algún curso estilo Píldoras.

Pero me ha surgido la duda al empezar el Tema de JSP al instalar desde casa el software necesario si la versión de Tomcat 10 es compatible con mi versión de Eclipse 2022-03 .

En clases asistenciales todo esta ya preinstalado y nosotros nos limitamos a usarlos pero recuerdo al profesor comentar algo respecto a la compatibilidad de la versión 9 pero ahora consigo caer en que fue lo que dijo.

Si fuerais tan amables de ayudarme os lo agradecería. Voy a utilizarlo para JSP, MVC y futuras cosas del estilo para mis estudios.

Gracias

Comment: Y qué dice la documentación al respecto?

Comment: El problema con tomcat 10 es que usa los paquetes de `jakarta.*` en lugar de `javax.*`, por tanto, puedes tener bastantes conflictos dependiendo del paquete que estés usando. Toda la especificación de `Servlet` y todos los paquetes que conformaban `JavaEE` cambiaron de nombre, por lo que puedes tener bastantes problemas, sobre todo con paquetes de terceros. Por ejemplo, si tu código importa algo de `javax.*`, no correrá en tomcat 10. Yo usaría tomcat 9 por ahora.

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias Jaime por tu explicación tan bien redactado y entendible para alguien que comienza como yo !!!